# Using Brackets for PHP files

Tags: php, wampserver, adobe-brackets

I currently have wampserver running and I'm trying to do live preview of a php file using Brackets.io. However when I click live preview I'm getting

```
Project settings for: Getting Started
Live preview base URL: ______________
```

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php1p3.html) on running PHP scripts.
My php file is in C:/wamp/wwww/php_proj1/php1.php so I've been trying to put this in my "Base URL"

```
http://localhost/php_proj1/php1.php
```

However everytime when I type that and enter it, it just asks me for the "Live Preview Base URL" again and nothing happens. I also tried putting the URL in my 'File->Project settings' and that also didn't work. I'm just running a basic php script that echos some words.

It works when I manually type

```
http://localhost/php_proj1/php1.php
```

in my Chrome URL but not when I use Bracets live preview.

What am I missing or doing wrong? Do I need to config anything in my wampserver? I've just started learning php and using wampserver so I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm following these 2 tutorials on doing this and it's just not working for me. 
[tutorial 1](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php1p3.html) and [tutorial 2](http://aldentec.com/blog/using-brackets-with-wamp/)

EDIT2: Found my mistake.. I did not do File->Open Folder to open the folder that I was working on... Thanks to everyone that helped me with this, I will definitely not make this mistake again. sigh

Comment: IIRC, you need a Chrome plug-in to allow live debugging from Brackets

Comment: What exactly do I need? Can you explain a little bit more?
I can do live preview when I run my html files, just can't seem to make it work for PHP.

Comment: can you try this "./php_proj1/php1.php" as your base url?

Comment: I tried it, and again, the dialog just closes and opens up again and asking me to input the "Live preview base URL" all over again.

Comment: have you followed this? https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Use-Brackets#lp-custom-server

Comment: this should work: https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Brackets-Server-Smoke-Tests

Comment: @Mawg You don't need a Chrome plugin to use Live Preview in Brackets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found my mistake. I did not do File->Open Folder to open the folder that I was working on...

Answer (score 6):

The `Live Preview Base Url` should be set to the same url that you would use to launch your project in a browser.

So if you have a project in `C:/wamp/wwww/php_proj1/` you would launch that project in a browser by entering `http://localhost/php_proj1/php1.php` therefore that is what Brackets is expecting to be entered into the `Base Url` field minus the actual script file name.

Remember the DocumentRoot of localhost is pointing to the folder `C:/wamp/www/`

So enter

```
http://localhost/php_proj1/
```

into the dialog that requests the Base Url.

Assuming you are editing the file `php1.php` at the time you clicked the Live Preview icon that is the script that will be run in the browser.

**Oh and of course** you have to have WAMPServer and therefore Apache up and running when you do this as it is running the code through Apache so that the PHP code can be interpreted.

Comment: I found another [tutorial](http://aldentec.com/blog/using-brackets-with-wamp/) on this and it didn't say to have Apache. I'm just wondering do I have to have it? And again, I tried putting in the Base url you have but it's not working and the dialog just keeps showing up asking for the Base Url over and over again no matter what I put.

Comment: You have to use LIVE PREVIEW is you have PHP Code in our project, and Live Preview means run on a real web server i.e. WAMPServer or something similiar

Comment: It's still not working :( This is driving me maddddddd

Comment: Are you sure that WAMPServer is running and the `W` icon is green?

Comment: Yes, is says it's running and the W icon is green.

Answer (score 2):

1. Try the same thing but with a simple HTML file.
2. Try launching your project with PHP's built-in server. Open a terminal/cmd window and go to the folder `php_proj1`. Now execute `php -S localhost:8000`. Now set your Live preview path to `http://localhost:8000/`. If this one does work, then there may be a problem with Wamp.

Now remember that no matter what, you're not supposed to contain a file in the Live Preview path, but only a folder path. When you contain it, you get to this URL: `http://server/file.php/file.php` (double) and that's not exactly what you want...

If none of these work - there may be a problem with either your computer, Brackets, Chrome, or both. Try to reinstall them (Brackets first).

Comment: I was able to live preview a html file inside my `php_proj1` folder .
And I'm not sure how to do your #2 since my cmd isn't set up to use php. 

Could it be that I still need to config my WAMPserver? Since Brackets is able to run html fine but just not php

Answer (score 0):

My two cents, is the name of the project `php_proj1` ? If not you'll have to use `http://localhost/` as your base URL.

Also (When you are using Brackets) check the content of the Chrome Network tab. F12 Developer Tools -> Network -> Filter -> Documents

Try to investigate the URLs, probably that'll give you some insight

Comment: My php1.php file is in the folder 'php_proj1' which is in my C:\wamp\www\php_proj1 

When I check the content of the chrome network tab nothing was recorded or there wasn't anything there.

Comment: You'll have to reload the page after activating the chrome developer tools. Regarding the project name, [this](http://aldentec.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/brackets_projectsettings_2.png) image shows that the project name in that tutorial is `WWW` similarly if your project name is `WWW` your Base URL is `http://localhost`